# Shell Script - tar comand mistaking archive name for directory

Tags: linux, bash

My Shell Script, a gutted backup script alternates between seemingly mistaking what I intend to be the archive file for the source directory and giving an output which claims I am trying to create an empty archive which I believe means it is still trying to use the archive name as the source. This only occurs when I supply a shell variable as the archive parameter, trying regular strings works perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATETIME=$(date +'%y/%m/%d-%H_%M_%S')
SRC='/home/benny/test/'
DST='backups'
GIVENAME='benny-backup'
ARCHIVE="$GIVENAME-$DATETIME.tar.gz"

echo $DATETIME
echo $SRC
echo $ARCHIVE

tar -zcvf $ARCHIVE  $SRC 
# if tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz" $SRC; the
```

The following is the output from the code:

```
18/11/15-00_10_02
/home/benny/test/

tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

This is the output I was having before I amended the above code to use only one variable created from concatenating the two initial ones:

```
18/11/15-00_12_51
/home/benny/test/

tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar (child): : Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/home/benny/test/
/home/benny/test/price.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: `##!/bin/bash` has too many `#`. It should just be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Is that in the real script or a copying error?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script. Then you'll see each command as it's executed.

Comment: Don't use all-uppercase variable names. By convention those names are used for environment variables.

Comment: Make sure your script has Unix newlines, not Windows CRLF. Use `dos2unix filename` to fix it.

Comment: A copying error, it isn't like that in the script. I did as you said and go the following: `+ echo 18/11/15-00_34_04
18/11/15-00_34_04
+ echo /home/benny/test/
/home/benny/test/
+ echo benny-backup-18/11/15-00_34_04.tar.gz
benny-backup-18/11/15-00_34_04.tar.gz
+ tar -zcvf benny-backup-18/11/15-00_34_04.tar.gz /home/benny/test/
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar (child): benny-backup-18/11/15-00_34_04.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/home/benny/test/
/home/benny/test/price.txt`

Comment: what do new lines have to do with it ?

Comment: I saw a blank filename, that might come from an extraneous CR in a filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filenames can't have `/` in them, since those are directory separators. Change the format of your date to use different delimiters.

```
DATETIME=$(date +'%y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been annoying me all evening